Custom ExceptionHandler in Laravel 11 - How to get HTML of error
I had many apps in Laravel where I have a personalized ExceptionHandler that sends the error by email so I can be notified if an app generantes and error and have the details.
Now, in laravel 11, they changed the exceptions to the bootstrap app but I can't get the same proccess working.
I have this in Laravel 10:
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        $previousValue = config("app.debug");
        config(["app.debug" => true]);
        $htmlError = parent::render($request, $e)->getContent();
        config(["app.debug" => $previousValue]);
        
        ...
        //Some more code that sends an email with this $htmlError has attached file in a email.

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}

With this I can't generate the Laravel error with Ignition, get the full html as if I have app.debug set to true, send it by email but, to the user, render the error page as normally, with app.debug correctly set (in production false, in dev true).
This way I always have the full html error and the final user sees what I want him to see that in production is a generic sorry page.
Now in Laravel 11 I have not found a way to do this. All internal functions of the ExceptionHandler are protected and can't access to them so in bootstrap/app.php, in:
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {
    
    }
}

I can't do anything but make a full custom view generation, but I want to avoid that, I want to use the already made by laravel, the new page that replaces the Ignition one.
Tried this, but the app execution gets stucked:
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {
        dd($exceptions->handler->render($request,$e));
    }
}

In the report method I have achived a little more, but not enough:
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->respond(function (Response $response) {
        $html = $response->getContent();
    }
}

I have the html in the response content but the problem is that is already generated with the value of app.debug so, in production I don't get the full error page, I get the standard sorry page.
I tried that, but is not working, don't know why:
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $appDebug = config("app.debug");
    config(["app.debug" => true]);

    $exceptions->respond(function (Response $response) {
        $html = $response->getContent();
    }

    config(["app.debug" => $appDebug]);
}

If I made a dd(config('app.debug')) just after changing the value to true it sais it's in true but is generating the sorry page. And I have another problem. This is the final response so, what I get by email is what end user is going to see and I don't want my end usesrs to see the full error.
Has anyone know how to migrate this to laravel 11?.
Thank you so much

I could resolve it, for anyone who needs it. The key was to clone the $exceptions->handler BEFORE to personalize the render function to avoid infinite bucle.
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $handler = clone $exceptions->handler;

    $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) use ($handler) {
        $previousValue = config("app.debug");
        config(["app.debug" => true]);

        $htmlError = $handler->render($request, $e)->getContent();

        config(["app.debug" => $previousValue]);
    
        //Code that sends the email
    });
});

Now, this works if you have Ignition, because is a custom error reporting sistem but if not, this generates the ugly symphony error page.
This is because on loading laravel it checks if app.debug is true or false and then loads some things about error reporting in the FoundationServiceProvider so, we need to "reload" them this way each time we change the app debug value:
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
$handler = clone $exceptions->handler;

$exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) use ($handler) {
        $fsp = new \Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider(app());

        $previousValue = config("app.debug");
        config(["app.debug" => true]);
        $fsp->register();

        $htmlError = $handler->render($request, $e)->getContent();

        config(["app.debug" => $previousValue]);
        $fsp->register();
    
        //Code that sends the email
    });
});

Maybe is not the best optimized way, i'm all open to any more simple suggestions.
Thank you very much
